# Hibernate: How can I know the children is dirty or not?

Tags: hibernate

There are two Parent/Children relationship entities.
And only have the mapping configuration in child's hbm.xml file. Like this:

```
    <many-to-one 
    name="child"
    class="com.Child"
    update="true"
    insert="true"
    cascade="save-update">
        <column not-null="false" name="PARENT_ID"></column>
   </many-to-one>
```

No `<one-to-many>` configuration in parent's hbm.xml.

Now I want to use ClassMetaData to get all the properties from the entity to verify it dirty or not. But I cannot get the `child` properties from ClassMetaData because it not configured.

But When I use session.saveAndUpdate(parentEntity), Hibernate knows the child is dirty and can update dirty child entity. How the Hibernate do that? Is there anyway that I can get the dirty state of the child entity?

Comment: You mean like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268466/how-does-hibernate-detect-dirty-state-of-an-entity-object ?

Answer (score 1):

Some googling reveals that there is no 'simple' way. You need to use [hibernate interceptors](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html) for this. Your use case is explained in [this blog](http://www.suryasuravarapu.com/2005/09/hibernate-dirty-check-interceptor.html).