# How does hibernate detects the changes when I have modified the entity in session

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to know how things work inside Hibernate.

So, I have a person in DB whoes name is "Peter";

```
Session session = SessionFactory.openSession();
Person p = session.get(Person.class, 1);//Peter's id is 1
System.out.println(p.getName());//output : Peter
p.setName("Joey");
session.flush();
session.close();
```

And now this person's name in DB have changed to "Joey".

How did that happened?

when I changed the person's name. How did hibernate detected the changes?

Comment: @SajanChandran how ,when did hibernate detect that?

Comment: This link explains [how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268466/how-does-hibernate-detect-dirty-state-of-an-entity-object) hibernate detects the changes and execute appropriate queries.

Answer (score 2):

The [Session#flush()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#flush%28%29) method makes the data that is currently in the session synchronized with what is in the database.

According to the javadoc:

> Flushing is the process of synchronizing the underlying persistent
>   store with persistable state held in memory.

Comment: thanks, but I wonder how does Session know I have changed the person

Comment: Well, I guess `Person` is a mapping class (related to the `PERSON` table in the db), isn't it ?

Comment: is that mean When I call session.flush , session will detect the changes?

Comment: When you instantiate the `Person` class, it's associated with the current `Session`. When the session flushes, it synchronizes the database with all the associated classes.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you used the method session.get (refer to the [doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#get%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29) ) and this in turn return a  persistent instance,

Persistent instances are tracked by the Hibernate session and changes are persisted to the database at session flush time. Therefore if you made changes to a persistent instances, those changes will be propagated to database on session flush

Persistent entities are detached from the session via Session.evict(), Session.clear() and Session.close() calls.

Comment: Are you sure that `session.flush()` make underlying db changes? I think, after `flush()`, the changes are still as Uncommitted changes, and real changes will be at commit time. You can inspect db with SQL command after `flush` but not before `commit`.

Comment: This is the default hibernate behaviour, unless specified otherwise in the flush mode http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html