# Spring Boot JPA Attach a Detached Entity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Imagine you have a common scenario where you iterate through a list of records. You want to manipulate each record inside a loop.

```
for (final var e : repository.findAll()) {
  manipulate(e)
}
```

A record contains mapped entities that are lazy loaded.

```
public class Record {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "record", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<SubRecord> set = new HashSet<>();
}
```

There are two common solutions

1. You use eager loading that is not a good idea in most cases because of performance issues
2. You use @Transactional annotation.

To use @Transactional you have to split the iteration and the manipulate method into two classes to make Spring able to create proper proxy entites otherwise both will run in the same transaction or you have to wait the complete loop to complete before a transaction is committed.

When manipulate() method is inside another service class you have to attach the e object back. You can do that with repo.findById(e.getId()) but it feels ugly. Is there a more elegant way to handle this situation or is there a better way to attach a detached entity back?

Comment: If you know you need to access all 'lazy' attributes in the entities being returned, why are you using a general fetch query that is only partially populating the entity? This is where something like an entity graph would help, since you know upfront you'll need your 'set' property fetched for this one use case but not in others. See fetch/load graphs which can tell your provider what additional properties need to be fetched for this request, so it can do so efficiently upfront instead of extending the transaction unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

> When manipulate() method is inside another service class you have to
> attach the e object back. You can do that with
> repo.findById(e.getId()) but it feels ugly.

The above is not true. If the iteration loop is inside a method marked with `@Transactional` then the nested manipulation will not produce a detached object. The objects iterated from the loop will become detached only when the original method marked with `@Transactional` ends.

I think you need to check how the `equals` and `hashcode` methods are defined for `SubRecord.class` as to ensure that `hibernate` is able to detect your manipulations in elements inside this `set` during `dirty-checking`.

Normally the `equals` and `hashcode` methods do not matter for hibernate to be able to observe attached entity changes during `dirty-checking` but there is an [exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5268617/7237884) in case your parent entity (ex `Record`) holds a reference to a `Set` in which case `hibernate` will consider the `equals` and `hashcode` method to understand if that `set` field was modified or not.

Another workaround if you are not able or don't want to update the `equals` and `hashcode` of `SubRecord.class` would be for you to create a new HashSet and add all the existing elements of the previous contained set in your parent entity (`Record`) after finishing the manipulation of `Record` (if it contained some manipulations in nested `SubRecords`). This way the dirty checking would be able to understand there are some changes to the field of type `Set` since it's reference would have changed.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "record", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<SubRecord> set = new HashSet<>();
```

This could work like `e.setSet(new HashSet<>(e.getSet()));`

Also consider changing the name of the field from `set` to something more relevant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you missed the point. The question is how to make manipulate() transactional without the need to make the complete loop transactional because then you have to wait for the complete loop to ends before a change in the database appears.

Comment: Your actual question in your question (`Is there a more elegant way to handle this situation or is there a better way to attach a detached entity back?`), differs from what you ask in this very comment (`how to make manipulate() transactional without the need to make the complete loop transactional because then you have to wait for the complete loop to ends before a change in the database appears`).